# SQLite Math Problems

Tags: sqlite

```
ROUND(SUM(price)-(SUM(price*TAX/100.0)+SUM(purchaseprice)),2) as profit = i get 227.8 as Profit
```

When i calculate them by my self i get 227.81 as Profit.

```
ROUND(SUM(price)-(SUM(price*TAX/100.0)+SUM(purchaseprice)),2)  as profit...GROUP BY productname (how i calculate it one by one i get the sum of 227.81)
```

Does SQLite have Problems calculating and Rounding floating points? I have already tried to change the type to numeric, real .... Maybe i can do the Math differently any ideas?

Comment: Never do money calculations with floating point. Either use a special decimal/money type (sqlite has none) or use integers to do your calculations. Otherwise you will trip over this kind of problems all over the place.

Comment: Thank you schlenk, so i should save the values as integer and return them as profit/100?

Comment: That surely works better, yes. Or store as many digits as you need, financial stuff is usually explicit with how many digits you should calculate.

Comment: is there a way to remove the floating points while doing the math in query